# How to see unsynchronized messages of a mirror in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm testing a RMQ cluster that we've set up. When a node recovers and rejoins the cluster, some queues (depending on if there are messages in the queue) are `unsynchronized` with the new node (ha-sync-mode=manual).

My question is: Can I know which messages are **synchronized** with a specific node and which **are not**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see this information.